# Tesseract with Python

Tags: python, captcha, tesseract

Всем привет. Мне нужно расшифровать простую капчу. Решил использовать Tesseract. Капча выглядит следующим образом. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую такой код:

```
import pytesseract
import os
import argparse
try:
    import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, imread
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance

path = 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/snad/captcha.png'

def solve_captcha(path):

    image = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
    image = ImageOps.autocontrast(image)

    filename = "{}.png".format(os.getpid())
    image.save(filename)

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    argparser.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image to be OCR'd")
    args = vars(argparser.parse_args())
    path = args["image"]
    print('-- Resolving')
    captcha_text = solve_captcha(path)
    print('-- Result: {}'.format(captcha_text))
```

После запуска получаю ошибку:

> usage: test2.py [-h] -i IMAGE
>
> test2.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image

Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: «the following arguments are required» → «требуются следующие аргументы»

Comment: У вас скрипт вываливается по ошибке argparser - он требует, чтобы картинка передавалась как параметр к скрипту. либо передавайте картинку как параметр, либо отключите argparser